# Convert text to JSON return some problems

Tags: python, json, string

I have a text like this:

`text = "Le développement du digital dans le domaine des ressources humaines soulève quatre défis majeurs : une disruption sans précédent de l’environnement économique, une marchandisation des individus, une ‘réinvention’ du travail collaboratif et une robotisation inéluctable au sein des organisations. Chacun de ces enjeux nécessite la mise en œuvre de changements de positionnement pour garantir à la fonction RH une place de choix au cœur de la stratégie de l’entreprise."`

and want to turn it into a JSON format to use it later, because the function I want to use it accepts only JSON format.

So i am using this code to turn it into JSON:

```
text= json.dumps(text)
```

But my output goes like this:

`"Le d\u00e9veloppement du digital dans le domaine des ressources humaines soul\u00e8ve quatre d\u00e9fis majeurs : une disruption sans pr\u00e9c\u00e9dent de l\u2019environnement \u00e9conomique, une marchandisation des individus, une \u2018r\u00e9invention\u2019 du travail collaboratif et une robotisation in\u00e9luctable au sein des organisations. Chacun de ces enjeux n\u00e9cessite la mise en \u0153uvre de changements de positionnement pour garantir \u00e0 la fonction RH une place de choix au c\u0153ur de la strat\u00e9gie de l\u2019entreprise."`

Comment: Json dumps has correctly encoded the non ASCII characters, and they will later be decoded when the json string will be converted back. So what is the problem here?

Comment: it doesn't decode them later, the function am talking about is an API and it gets the output as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, my code cannot be formatted in comments.

What you show is the normal json encoding, and json will later decode it back:

```
import json

text = "Le développement du digital dans le domaine des ressources humaines soulève quatre défis majeurs : une disruption sans précédent de l’environnement économique, une marchandisation des individus, une ‘réinvention’ du travail collaboratif et une robotisation inéluctable au sein des organisations. Chacun de ces enjeux nécessite la mise en œuvre de changements de positionnement pour garantir à la fonction RH une place de choix au cœur de la stratégie de l’entreprise."

js = json.dumps(text)
print(js)
```

gives:

```
"Le d\u00e9veloppement du digital dans le domaine des ressources humaines soul\u00e8ve quatre d\u00e9fis majeurs : une disruption sans pr\u00e9c\u00e9dent de l\u2019environnement \u00e9conomique, une marchandisation des individus, une \u2018r\u00e9invention\u2019 du travail collaboratif et une robotisation in\u00e9luctable au sein des organisations. Chacun de ces enjeux n\u00e9cessite la mise en \u0153uvre de changements de positionnement pour garantir \u00e0 la fonction RH une place de choix au c\u0153ur de la strat\u00e9gie de l\u2019entreprise."
```

And it is correctly decoded back with `loads`:

```
t2 = json.loads(js)
print(t2 == text)
```

gives:

```
True
```

Comment: i found a working solution: text.decode() at the end, thanks for your help.

Comment: but json.loads(text) is working waaaaay better. thanks again